# How do you increase headrule length in fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, lengths

It's pretty well-known how to increase the headrule width, but how do I increase its length (i.e. let it run into the margin).

Comment: according to the fancyhdr manual `\fancyhfoffset[L]{1cm}` will make the header stick out an extra cm on the left

Answer (score 10):

Use the following command in your defs:

```
\fancyheadoffset{\textwidth}
```

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE \fancyheadoffset{\textwidth}]

Comment: You might mention also the optional argument to add to the width only on one side.

Comment: As well, you are adding `\textwidth` length at an inappropriate place. Try to add `\usepackage[textwidth=2.7in]{geometry}` before the `\fancy...` commands: you get a different result (the line is not across the whole page).